Firebase Authentication with Apple sign in Flutter works for iOS but not working for Android
When I trigger the Apple Sign in with the below codes:
Future<UserCredential> signInWithApple() async {
 final appleProvider = AppleAuthProvider();
 appleProvider.addScope('email');
 // appleProvider.setCustomParameters({
 //   'client_id': 'com......firebase', // service ID
 // }); // client_id is reserved
 return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithProvider(appleProvider);
}

It launches the chrome with proper information from the service I created at Apple developer, it seems that the sign in process finishes properly. But when it gets back to the Android App, I get the following error message:
FirebaseAuthException:
Code: invalid-credential,
Message: HttpMetadata{status=400, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE, cacheDurationJava=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null, filename=null, lastModified=null, retryAfter=null, crossOriginEmbedderPolicy=null, crossOriginOpenerPolicy=null, crossOriginResourcePolicy=null, permissionsPolicies=[], headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK, contentSecurityPolicies=[], originTrials=[], reportToHeaders=[], varyHeaderNames=[], cookieList=[]}},
StackTrace: null
I have created the keys and services twice and double checked everything with Apple developer, put in the call back as suggested by Firebase with domain.
Put the values in Firebase Auth as it is required, but it seems not to be working and the error persists.
If I cancel the error code is "web-context-canceled" so I think it is okay.
If anybody faced similar issues any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

and I have run 'flutterfire configure' properly after changes in my firebase console, updated my Plists for iOS accordingly, apple sign in in iOS is working fine. google sign in in both iOS and Android is working fine too.

have you followed this ?
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/social/#apple

Please check Apple >> Android from your link:
At the moment, the preferable solution is blocked by this issue.
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/2691

I followed this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth

a bit more detail on the error:  com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired. [ Error getting access token from https://appleid.apple.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, response: OAuth2TokenResponse{params: error=invalid_client, ...

Have you logged the value of the credential coming back from apple? "FirebaseAuthException: Code: invalid-credential"

I am not sure how to log those value separately. But the problem was there was a white space before my team ID that I could not find after several checks, and then when I was specifically checking for white spaces, I noticed it.

There was a space before the teamID in my firebase auth setup! Please check for white spaces for teamID, Service ID etc.

Apple sign in for android is kind of redundant imo, but if you still wanna implement it,
check out: https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple
you might have to Create a Service ID
it says:
The Service ID is only needed for a Web or Android integration. If you only intend to integrate iOS you can skip this step.


It is a requirement for the app. And service ID is created and in service, I can see the app name mentioned in service while logging in. The problem occurs when the login is done and it gets back to my android app, that is when the exception is thrown.

I am pretty sure you need to make this available in order to host on the app store.

for apple it is implemented and working fine from the beginning. For android, apple sign in seems redundant to me too, but it was an app requirement.

Please check if email-enumeration-protection  is enabled. It will be enabled by default and can throw that auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired error.
Try disabling email-enumeration-protection and check if Apple sign in works smoothly for Android.

this helped getting a bit more detail on the error. The details of the error is posted on a comment of Original Post.

Okay, did you follow this documentation thoroughly? -> https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple#integration

I followed this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth
